# How to place an axis on a hierarchical visNetwork in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

When plotting a visHierarchicalLayout, visNetwork allows you to set an x or y position for nodes which can be meaningful. So how can I add an axis to the generated javascript plot? In my case I am using a vertical layout, so would want a y-axis somehow.